# Meteor .find() from Collection returns [object Object]

Tags: mongodb, object, collections, find, meteor

Running on Ubuntu

**Data.js**

```
//Collections
Database = new Meteor.Collection('data');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.main.data = function () {
    var c = Database.find();
    return c;
  };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

**data.html**

```
<head>
  <title>data</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  {{data}}
</template>
```

I inserted into the db using mongo:

```
> db.Database.insert({title: 'ShouldWork'});
> db.Database.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5296403855ee6e1350b35afb"), "title" : "ShouldWork" }
```

Yet when I run the site it just returns [object Object]..

There should be autopublish on and insecure, 
This has become quite the roadblock for me to clear in learning the framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected. This is because the results of `.find()` are always a cursor and have multiple objects.
You have to decide which one you want or if you want to loop through each one.

1) You want to use one result:

```
 var c = Database.findOne();
```

or 2) You want to iterate through each one:

```
{{#each data}}
    {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Additionally be sure to use the property of `{{data}}` because `{{data}}`, even with `findOne` is still an `[Object object]`. You should use something like `{{data.title}}` instead depending on the property you want to use.

Comment: Now nothing gets displayed :S

Comment: Figured it out, for some reason mongo db was not actually adding into the collection :/

Answer (score 1):

**How to access data in Mongo DB from html ?**

First of all you need to have the ***Mongo DB instance present in global variable*** i:e it must be declared in any .js file as below. *It is not part of client or server code*

Say we create a Collection of Events in one of the js files.

```
    EventList = new Mongo.Collection('Events');
```

Now, in order to access all the objects from HTML, we would need a ***Helper function inside client in our .js file***. Below is Helper used:-

```
Template.viewEvent.helpers  ({ 
    //NOTE : 'event' is the name of variable from html template
    'event' : function () {
         //returns list of Objects for all Events
         return EventList.find().fetch();
     }
    'users' : function () {
         //returns reference to Document for all users
         return UserList.find().fetch();
     }

});
```

Just left to ***Display content on .html***:-

Say EventList Collection has fields Event_Name, Event_Date. Below would be the html template code

```
<template name="viewEvent">
   <h2>View Event</h2>
   <!-- Iterate on all Objects fetched by the Helper Class-->
   {{#each event}}
      {{Event_Name}} : {{Event_Date}} 
   {{/each}}
```